# Given a directed graph and a vertex v, find all cycles that go through v?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

Given a set of uniquely numbered items that each has three attributes `id`, `from` and `two` in the following format,

```
{id, from, to}
```

we would like to find all cycles that a particular item participates in.

For example, given the following items

```
{id:1,  from:h, to:l},
{id:2,  from:b, to:e},
{id:3,  from:p, to:q},
{id:4,  from:e, to:h},
{id:5,  from:e, to:g},
{id:6,  from:l, to:m},
{id:7,  from:m, to:k},
{id:8,  from:k, to:i},
{id:9,  from:g, to:i},
{id:10, from:i, to:b},
```

we can construct a directed graph

[image]

Each item is *connected* or *related* to another by the `from` and `to` attributes and there can be items that are not related to any others (for example the item with `id = 3` in the example above).

The input is the `id` of an arbitrary item within the array and the output of the algorithm is the list of cycles that each item participates in. For example, based on the image above, examples of the expected output are:

1. Given the `id = 7`, the expected result is:

   An array containing this single array (or its equivalent circular linked list).
   That is, the items connected by the blue line.
   If the items in the inner array are rotated by N, it's ok.

   ```
   output = [
       [
           {id:7,  from:m, to:k},
           {id:8,  from:k, to:i},
           {id:10, from:i, to:b},
           {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
           {id:4,  from:e, to:h},
           {id:1,  from:h, to:l},
           {id:6,  from:l, to:m}
       ]
   ]
   ```
2. Given the `id = 2`, the expected result is:

   An array containing two arrays (or their equivalent circular linked list).
   That is, the two collections of items connected by the red and the blue line.
   If the items in the inner arrays are rotated by N, it's ok.

   ```
   output = [
       [
           {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
           {id:5,  from:e, to:g},          
           {id:9,  from:g, to:i},
           {id:10, from:i, to:b}
       ],
       [           
           {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
           {id:4,  from:e, to:h},
           {id:1,  from:h, to:l},
           {id:6,  from:l, to:m},
           {id:7,  from:m, to:k},
           {id:8,  from:k, to:i},
           {id:10, from:i, to:b}
       ]
   ]
   ```

So, the questions is what could be the possible algorithm and data structure to resolve this problem? It's ok to have whatever time/space complexity. Optimizations can be performed later.

Comment: Why `10` has two edges to `2`?

Comment: The lines between `10´` and `2` are not edges, they indicate cycles within the graph.